# Passing Variable to the next page without form or URL extension

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a Link to go to exampleA.php, but i want to have a variable pass together with the link. of course the condition is not using URL extensions or form submitting.i search around and most people suggest ajax, but to me i am not just passing variable of the file i want to handle the variable when i am at the exampleA.php Page.
In exampleA.php i have code for example

`if(isset($_POST['Type'])){
    $Type=$_POST['Type'];
}`

with Ajax i am not able to handle the POST variable when i already reach the exampleA.php page.
just in case maybe i am wrong with my code.

```
<a class="example_anchor" href="TestB.php/" data-type="Activity">M</a>
    <script>
        $(".example_anchor").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var Type = $(this).data();
        var link = $(this).attr('href');
        $.ajax({
            url: link,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "text",
            data: { 
                Type:Type
            },
            error: function (msg) {
                alert("Fail");// Error handling
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                // Success handling

                     alert("You will now be redirected.");
                     window.location.replace(link);

            }
        });


        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Is there any error in your console ?

Comment: Can you not simply use locale storage or cookies? The problem with your code above is that `TestB.php` will only receive `$_POST['Type']` on the AJAX request. When you use `window.location.replace(link)`, that is a separate `GET` request and `$_POST` will be empty

Comment: Why can you not use a form submit or even easier, `TestB.php?Type=Activity`? Is there any actual reason for these restrictions?

Comment: requirement from the upper decision. i have to find ways around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I'd just [set a cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) before moving on to the next page.

```
$('.example_anchor[data-type]').on('click', function (e) {
  document.cookie = `type=${this.getAttribute('data-type')}` // note, very simplified
  return true
})
```

Then your PHP script should be able to access `$_COOKIE['type']`.

---

If `TestB.php` is not in the same path as the current resource, you may need to set the cookie `path` property. You may also want to set other properties like `expires` though the default will expire at the end of the session.

Comment: Wonderful, i never thought of it. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

try using session to send data without using form or url or ajax.

here's how to do it

1. Start a session on every page with the line `session_start();`
2. On the first page from where you want to send data, transfer that to session variable like `$_SESSION['transferdata']= "some data"`
3. On the next page, check like

   `if(isset($_SESSION['transferdata'])){
   // do whatever you want to do
   }`

Comment: To make it clear, i am using multiple links. each links have their possible variable, and all direct to the same page. over here your solution is great and easy, but how do i determined what data to send when a link is clicked. for what i know PHP has no click event like JavaScript.

Comment: oh wait, my eyes just opened. i can use ajax, and on destination php code i assign the variable. Thanks.